# Access cross account data uploaded by other user on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Suppose, I have 3 AWS Accounts :

- Account A having User A
- Account B having User B
- Account C having User C and Bucket: MyBucket

**User A** and **User B** uploads data to **MyBucket** in **Account C** 
Both users have permissions to read/write data in the bucket.

But they cannot  view the content of files uploaded by other account means **User A** cannot view the content of the file uploaded by 
**User B**

Is there any way to let my both users see the content of each other?

Comment: I don't see any reason why you can't achieve that.
Did you grant the A and B user the permission to List?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html

Comment: please add your policies to your questions, you might be missing the trust policy.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bucket policy is missing there:

```
 MyBucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref MyBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Action: ["s3:*"]
          Effect: Allow
          Resource:
          - !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${MyBucket}"
          - !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${MyBucket}/*"
          Principal:
            AWS:
            - !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AccountA}:role/cross-account-role"
            - !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AccountB}:role/cross-account-role"
```